# Remove HTML from a String and showing the Gists inside the script tags - Android

Tags: java, android, html

Trying to display the Github Gists from a String in a TextView.
When I clean the String from the HTML with 'Html.fromHtml()' -->

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="http://Lorem ipsum.com/Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">amet</a>,</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices lorem scelerisque year&#8217;s Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices lorem scelerisque<br />
</p>
<p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus</p>
<p><script src="https://gist.github.com/LoremIpsum/d3c4dff75f555a54aa0f.js"></script>Donec ac ultrices elit. Curabitur elementum pulvinar augue a congue. Phasellus in quam ligula.<script src="https://gist.github.com/dolorSitAmet/53ae35ddd74bb0837c12.js"></script></p>
```

* *I get the same result as when running the code snippet.*

How can I show the Gists like in the picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) tells us, the `Html.fromHtml()` method

> Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string

Unfortunately, the reference is a bit vague about which HMTL tags are supported. I searched around a bit, and the [source code at grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/text/Html.java#HtmlToSpannedConverter.convert%28%29) shows that the `<script>` tag is not evaluated.

So the answer to your question is: with a `TextView`, you can't. Use a `WebView` instead. Click [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) for a short introduction.

Comment: @kinsell - the WebView is not a full browser, it can be embedded in your app just like a TextView. You have to enable Javascript execution expressly. The [Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#AddingWebView) contains some code on how to achieve this. A good sample... I really would try to follow the reference and step by step include my own stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the well formed answer, I did try your solution webView.loadData(content,"text/html", null); but its not showing the gists

Comment: @kinsell - did you enable the javascript? try a simple alert first, to make sure the script executes at all

Comment: @kinsell - all of it? I mean, the gist as well?

Comment: Yes all of it, the only problem are the links, because they are sending me to the browser.

Comment: @kinsell - I've been reading a bit and that seems to be the best solution. One of my books says one should always use an own WebViewClient because the default behavior (links and redirecting) is different for different API levels. So, problem solved and learned something new as well :)

Comment: Can you suggest any new books for Android.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92575/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-kinsell).

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlCode));
```

It will do your job.

Comment: I mention in the post that I used that solution. And showed the output *When run code snippet. The Gists are empty spaces.